# Selecting an object using string names?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I built an object, to give hex code colored backgrounds dependant on the tag a post has.

example of object: ($tagcolor)

```
stdClass Object ( [school] => #113730 
                  [funny] => #ef5017 
                  [art] => #e2ba17 
                  [wow] => #164852 
                  [test] => #9bbb8e 
                )
```

and as an example of the code that I'm trying to use to display the background color: (I'm using laravel framework)

```
@foreach($links as $link)
      <?php $tag = $link->tags; ?>
      <span class="tagcolor" style="background: {{ $tagcolor->$tag }}"></span>
@endforeach
```

If I use simply normal text to select the object value, it works fine:

```
$tagcolor->test
```

Returns:

```
#9bbb8e
```

How can I select an object value via a string?

Comment: `$tagcolor->{'a string'}`

Comment: @DaveChen I gave that a try it returns "Undefined property: stdClass::$$tag" I also tried it without the single quotes, and it also returned an error.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: http://in1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#108320 read this object properties should not with $ sign.

Comment: Please print_r the object and tell us which property of the object you want. From the above object, you can select all the properties without the use of `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for additional help Dave, the answer below by Hans was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does laravel really allow regular php tags? I suspect not. This line probably doesn't work:

```
<?php $tag = $link->tags; ?>
```

This should allow you to omit that line:

```
  <span class="tagcolor" style="background: {{ $tagcolor->{$link->tags} }}"></span>
```

Comment: FYI - Laravel does allow regular PHP tags. But your answer is still better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<span class="tagcolor" style="background: {{ $tagcolor->$tag }}"></span>
```

to

```
<span class="tagcolor" style="background: {{ $tagcolor->{$tag} }}"></span>
```